# AngularJS custom filter function

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter, controller

Inside my controller, I would like to filter an array of objects. Each of these objects is a map which can contain strings as well as lists

I tried using `$filter('filter')(array, function)` format but I do not know how to access the individual elements of the array inside my function. Here is a snippet to show what I want.

```
$filter('filter')(array, function() {
  return criteriaMatch(item, criteria);
});
```

And then in the `criteriaMatch()`, I will check if each of the individual property matches

```
var criteriaMatch = function(item, criteria) {
  // go thro each individual property in the item and criteria
  // and check if they are equal
}
```

I have to do all these in the controller and compile a list of lists and set them in the scope. So I do need to access the `$filter('filter')` this way only. All the examples I found in the net so far have static criteria searches inside the function, they don't pass an criteria object and test against each item in the array.

Comment: Why do you need a filter? Usually filters are used from templates. Can you not just have a plain function in your controller if your are only using it from there?

Comment: instead of manually going thro each element of the array, i thought we could use the $filter('filter') functionality of angular (which will take care of iterating thro each element if we just specify the predicate function)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can use it like this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/vtNjEgmpItqxX5fdwtPi?p=preview

Like you found, `filter` accepts predicate function which accepts item
by item from the array.
So, you just have to create an predicate function based on the given `criteria`.

In this example, `criteriaMatch` is a function which returns a predicate
function which matches the given `criteria`.

template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:criteriaMatch(criteria)">
  {{ item }}
</div>
```

scope:

```
$scope.criteriaMatch = function( criteria ) {
  return function( item ) {
    return item.name === criteria.name;
  };
};
```

Comment: I will not be using this criteriaMatch function from the html.. how will I call it from inside the controller is this correct ? $filter('filter')(array, function(){ return criteriaMatch(item, criteria); });

Comment: If you are not using it in your template, defining filter does not give you any advantage.  You can simply define a simple javascript function, as it is even shorter there.  You can use native `filter` method in Array object: `array.filter(function(item){return item.name === criteria.name;})`

Comment: I do have a javascript function. just wanted to make sure that angular did not have an easier way of doing it.. i will accept your answer. thx.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you'd use `filter` within your AngularJS JavaScript (rather than in an HTML element).

In this example, we have an array of Country records, each containing a name and a 3-character ISO code.

We want to write a function which will search through this list for a record which matches a specific 3-character code.

Here's how we'd do it *without* using `filter`:

```
$scope.FindCountryByCode = function (CountryCode) {
    //  Search through an array of Country records for one containing a particular 3-character country-code.
    //  Returns either a record, or NULL, if the country couldn't be found.
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.CountryList.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.CountryList[i].IsoAlpha3 == CountryCode) {
            return $scope.CountryList[i];
        };
    };
    return null;
};
```

Yup, nothing wrong with that.

But here's how the same function would look, using `filter`:

```
$scope.FindCountryByCode = function (CountryCode) {
    //  Search through an array of Country records for one containing a particular 3-character country-code.
    //  Returns either a record, or NULL, if the country couldn't be found.

    var matches = $scope.CountryList.filter(function (el) { return el.IsoAlpha3 == CountryCode; })

    //  If 'filter' didn't find any matching records, its result will be an array of 0 records.
    if (matches.length == 0)
        return null;

    //  Otherwise, it should've found just one matching record
    return matches[0];
};
```

Much neater.

Remember that `filter` returns an array as a result (a list of matching records), so in this example, we'll either want to return 1 record, or NULL.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Additionally, if you want to use the filter in your controller the same way you do it here:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:criteriaMatch(criteria)">
  {{ item }}
</div>
```

You could do something like:

```
var filteredItems =  $scope.$eval('items | filter:filter:criteriaMatch(criteria)');
```

Comment: Alternatively, `var filteredItems = $filter('criteriaMatch')(items, criteria);`