# AngularJS filtering on categories

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I started playing with AngularJS earlier today and I decided to build a simple app that consists of categories containing items.

The app has a sidebar where the categories are listed (`aside.navigation`) and a main view where all the items are listed. My plan was to load all the items (`$scope.items`) into an `<ul>` and filter them when a user clicks on one of the categories in the sidebar.

I tried a couple of things, including a simple filter withing the HTML, and a custom filter function. But I just can't get it to work. What would be the best way to do this?

This is my HTML

```
<html ng-app="stash">
    ...
    <body ng-controller="StashCtrl">
        <div id="stash">
            <aside class="navigation">
                <h1 class="logo"><a href="#"><strong>stash</strong>.io</a></h1>
                <ul>
                    <li class="icon-latest active"><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
                    <li class="icon-star"><a href="#">Favorites</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="stash in stashes" class="icon-{{stash.icon}}"><a href="#">{{stash.title}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </aside>

            <section class="content">
                <header>
                    <h1>Inbox <span class="item-count">{{totalItems}}</span></h1>
                </header>
                <ul class="items clearfix">
                    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
                        <a ng-if="item.image != ''" href="#" class="has-image" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{item.image}})'}">
                            <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
                        </a>
                        <a ng-if="item.excerpt != ''" href="#">
                            <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
                            <p>{{item.excerpt}}</p>
                        </a>
                        <a ng-if="item.image == '' && item.excerpt == ''" href="#">
                            <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
    ...
</html>
```

And the JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('stash', []);

app.controller('StashCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {id: '1', stash: '1', title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit', excerpt: '', image: 'images/portfolio1.jpg'},
        {id: '2', stash: '1', title: 'Lorem ipsum', excerpt: '', image: 'images/portfolio4.jpg'},
        {id: '3', stash: '1', title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', excerpt: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, autem, repellat, asperiores, voluptates doloremque eaque suscipit beatae quisquam sint consequuntur illo minus ipsum optio officia alias ex veritatis libero veniam tempora fugit laborum facere vitae doloribus omnis aspernatur corporis rerum ad repudiandae accusamus placeat. Officia, aliquam, laborum sequi minima saepe et voluptatem! Consequuntur maiores veniam laboriosam quaerat quae delectus doloremque rem cumque aspernatur! Tenetur, beatae facere incidunt quae numquam vitae exercitationem quia saepe earum officiis porro asperiores id explicabo sapiente molestiae culpa atque facilis ipsa eligendi nobis quas eaque possimus temporibus nam mollitia distinctio dicta dolores. Expedita, quas aliquid modi!', image: ''},
        {id: '4', stash: '2', title: 'Lorem ipsum', excerpt: '', image: 'images/portfolio2.jpg'},
        {id: '5', stash: '', title: '5', excerpt: '', image: ''}
    ];
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.items.length;

    $scope.stashes = [
        {id: '1', title: 'Ideas', icon: 'lightbulb'},
        {id: '2', title: 'Onefinity Studios', icon: 'company'},
        {id: '3', title: 'OnefinityCMS', icon: 'star'}
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to set `search` to an object:

```
$scope.search = {};
```

And change the stash id on click in your stash list:

```
<a href ng-click="search.stash = stash.id">{{stash.title}}</a>
```

[**Here is a working demo.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TO2v198sVZzAdbmOCEck?p=preview)

If you want an active state just use `ng-class` and place it on your `li`:

```
<li ng-repeat="stash in stashes" ng-class="{'active': stash.id == search.stash}">...</li>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! But I do feel extremely stupid right now; when I tried it this way I added the `ng-click` to the `li` instead of the `a`... Shame on me.

Comment: The `li` should work too, your problem more likely was the `href="#"`.

Comment: By the way, would it be possible to use this method with a separate filter function? Since I would like to add an `.active` class to the `li`.

Comment: That's a great solution! Unfortunately I also want to be able to add the `.active` class the 'Latest' and 'Favorites' for example. So would it still work then?

And maybe I need the custom function for another reason later on. Is it hard to change this code to use a custom function?

Comment: It is just some more work. Have a look at [that question which is about custom filter functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16474091/983992). If you have problems with it I think it's better to ask another question.

Comment: I'll definitly look into that question. Thanks for the quick responses!

Answer (score 0):

The filter is filtering by a property called search but it doesn't exist.

One way to do this is to save the selected `stash` into a `currentStash` property on the scope, then filter by it...

```
<li ng-repeat="stash in stashes" class="icon-{{stash.icon}}">
    <a href="#" ng-click="$parent.currentStash = stash">{{stash.title}}</a>
</li>
```

And then change the filter to...

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter : { stash: currentStash.id }">
```

[**JsBin**](http://jsbin.com/bujecace/1/edit?html,js,output)