# How to filter second level ng-repeat in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an *array* of *objects* which I want to display as a `table` with `filter`. My filter with model `name` is filtering the deep *object* `family`. This works fine but not the way I want it to work...

**What I want:** Insert string to `input`, e.g. '*Ma*'. Now, I want it to display all items containing a *string* in `family` matching '*Ma*' - that means I want to **keep all the family members displayed as long as one string matches**. In my example this would be the filtered result:

```
Homer    Marge, Bart, Lisa, Maggie
Ned      Maude, Rod, Todd
```

**Example Code with snippet below:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tableData = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Homer', family: ['Marge', 'Bart', 'Lisa', 'Maggie']},
        {id: 2, name: 'Carl', family: []},
        {id: 3, name: 'Lenny', family: []},
        {id: 4, name: 'Clancy', family: ['Sarah', 'Ralph']},
        {id: 5, name: 'Ned', family: ['Maude', 'Rod', 'Todd']},
        {id: 6, name: 'Moe', family: []}
    ];
});
```

```css
table td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            Filter family members: <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in tableData">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <span ng-repeat="member in item.family | filter: name">
                    {{member}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the first `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter: name && {family: name}">
```

The key is to provide the name of the property you want to filter on. Here it is the property `family`.

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqmzb0ae/1/)** (Type *ma* in the search box)

Edit: And remove the filter you placed on the inner `ng-repeat`

Comment: I want to keep all the family members displayed as long as one string matches.

Comment: Forgot to remove the filter on the inner ng-repeat... See edit.

Comment: nice solution! Cleaner than mine. You could also use a filterBy service if you don't mind upgrading angular version

Comment: Well thanks for the solution but i don't understand the need of filter mine is working without fikter too

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a custom filter on the top ng-repeat. You can specify a function as the filter: [custom filter answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16479421/2945345). In this custom filter return all items in tableData that contain a match in the sub array.

Note: You could use lodash to help with this calculation.

Example: [plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/hRFgtkTxjphK8rrskPPO?p=preview)

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter:criteriaMatch(name)">
```

...

```
$scope.criteriaMatch = function( criteria ) {
    return function( item ) {
        if(!angular.isDefined(criteria) || criteria === "")
            return true;

        var results = _.filter(item.family, function(n) {
           if(_.contains(n.toUpperCase(), criteria.toUpperCase()))
           {
             return true;
           }
        });

        if(results.length !== 0)
          return true;

        else  return false;

    };
};
```

Comment: alternative to lodash would be to use a custom angularJs filter in the Js custom filter... which may be tidier

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without a custom filter, by providing a conditional filter on the first `ng-repeat`. For example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter: (name.length > 0 || '') && {family: name}">
```

You need the conditional because if you add a filter and remove it, the blank arrays wont be considered (angular quirk).

I have created a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dL8b27z0/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't keep the non-matching family members displayed.

Answer (score -1):

Do you try to use the filter in tableData?? Something like this:

`<input type="text" ng-model="family">`

And

`<tr ng-repeat="item in tableData | filter: family">`