# AngularJS orderBy expression with subtraction

Tags: angularjs

I have an expression

```
{{ product.SelectedProduct.BasePrice - product.SelectedProduct.Discount | currency  }}
```

I need to be able to order my products by the value of baseprice - discount.  Is there a way to do this?  So I want something like

```
{{product.SelectedProduct.ProductName | 
orderBy : product.SelectedProduct.BasePrice - product.SelectedProduct.Discount }}
```

New code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
            <span class="mktpl_productnm" ng-show="product.SelectedProduct.ProductName">{{product.SelectedProduct.ProductName || 'product not available' | orderBy: price }}</span>
            <span ng-hide="product.SelectedProduct.ProductName" class="field-validation-error">Product not available</span>
            <span ng-show="product.SelectedProduct.remaining < product.SelectedProduct.prodterm.minQuantity" class="field-validation-error">
                (Out of stock)
            </span>
        </div>

 vm.price = function (product) {
        debugger;
        return product.SelectedProduct.BasePrice - product.SelectedProduct.Discount;
    };
```

Comment: `orderBy` is used with `ng-repeat` -- how are you using it?

Comment: create a custom filter or add a property to each item in controller or service

Comment: you can also filter by function. @Explosion Pills, orderBy is a usual filter, nothing more.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm using it with a list of products.  I didn't write the code, I'm just trying to edit it.  Do you need me to add more code to my question?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov how do you filter by function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474091/angular-custom-filter-function or similar, internet is full of examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your example doesn't make much sense: orderBy applies to an array, to order the elements of this array. But `product.SelectedProduct.ProductName` is probably not an array.

Second: [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) says:

> expression    function(*)stringArray.<(function(*)|string)>=
>
> A predicate to be used by the comparator to determine the order of elements.
>
> Can be one of:
>
> function: Getter function. The result of this function will be sorted using the <, ===, > operator.
>   [...]

So, all you need is a function in the scope that returns the element to compare for a given element of the array:

```
$scope.reducedPrice = function(product) {
    return product.SelectedProduct.BasePrice - product.SelectedProduct.Discount;
};
```

and in the view:

```
{{ productArray | orderBy:reducedPrice }}
```

Another option would be to precompute the reducedPrice and store it as an attribute or the product, and then simply use

```
{{ productArray | orderBy:'reducedPrice' }}
```

Comment: JB I edited my code above to show you what I did.  It's not working.  Am I missing something?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, you're missing something. orderBy is used to sort elements of an **array** (of products, in this case). But you're applying it to the name of one product. That makes no sense. That's the very first sentence of my answer.