# Filter by property value in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Is there a way to filter by property, something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people| filter: {age>20}" >
```

that *without* a custom filter function?

Comment: No. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

you can define a filter function inside controller   [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474091/angularjs-custom-filter-function)

or see [Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-if` directive for this

```
 ng-repeat="person in people" ng-if="person.age > 20"
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want to use custom `filter`, you can apply `ng-show`, somthing like:

`<td ng-show ="person.age > 20">{{person}}</td>`

Regarding your question - you can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter:{person.age > 20}">
```

Angular Expression [Doc.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Regards

Comment: thanks, this code, however, does not use angular "filter"s.

Comment: Modified answer as per your question. My bad for misunderstanding question.