# How to write filter for multiple conditions in html?

Tags: angularjs, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIKSn.png)I have the code given below. 
I am using story owner and story state.

```
ng-repeat="item in IterationStories | 
filter: {Story: {storyOwner: filterRequestor}} | 
filter: {Story: {state: filterKey}} " //when I select state it is working
```

Comment: Can you be more brief about your problem  and formalize your question properly?

Comment: you can use filter with a custom function where you check your conditions

have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474091/angularjs-custom-filter-function

Comment: That is applying two separate filters chaining them individually, so it will filter your results with condition one, run the results through a second filter with condition two etc.

Comment: hi ste2425, Like you said it is executing the first one and later the second but i dono how to move to first one.

Comment: Can you give us IterationStories json data?

Answer (score 1):

You find a good example on the official Angular filter documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

So if your "item" object look like this:

```
{
   storyOwner: 'something',
   state: 'deleted',
}
```

You can implement the filter like this:

```
<label>Story owner <input ng-model="search.storyOwner"></label>
<label>State <input ng-model="search.state"></label>
<table>

  <tr ng-repeat="item in IterationStories | filter:search">

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hi robert, i am using check box filter not search box.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    //for third solution 
    $scope.myFilter = function (item) {
        return (item.storyOwner == $scope.Story.storyOwner || item.state:$scope.Story.filterKey );
    }
```

```html
<!--first solution-->
    ng-repeat="item in IterationStories | filter:{storyOwner: filterRequestor, state: filterKey} "

<!--second solution-->
    ng-repeat="item in IterationStories | filter: {Story: {storyOwner: filterRequestor, state: filterKey}}"

<!--third solution-->
    ng-repeat="item in IterationStories | filter:myFilter"
```

Comment: Can you write , want to filter data (json) ?

Comment: hi baris ciraci, i have also tried all these solutions. i dont want to filter json only in HTML.

Comment: What you want to filter data ?