# how to show a spinner using a filter in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am using a filter to show some values in a table. Values fetching by ajax calls and I want to show a spinner while the values are fetching. So I wrote:

```
app.filter("fetchedValue", function(){
    return function(fetchedValue){
            if(angular.isUndefined(fetchedValue)){
                    return "image";//this is the spinner
            }else if(fetchedValue === null){
                    return "NA";
            }
            else{
                    return fetchedValue;
            }
    }
});
```

It is not working. I am not sure how to get the spinner when the value is undefined. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what a filter is for. The function should return true or false depending if you want the value given to the function to be filtered or not.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter and [AngularJS custom filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474091/angularjs-custom-filter-function)

To answer your question though, forget about the filter, and just use an `ng-if` or an `ng-show` or an `ng-hide` on an `<img>` when the value is undefined.

```
<img ng-hide="fetchedValue" src="spinner.gif" />
```

This assumes that your fetched value is always truthy. A more robust solution would be to set a flag in a finally block of the request promise, and then `ng-hide` based on that flag.

Comment: I think we can use filter to format the values in angular and this is what I am doing in that filter.

Comment: Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should. The purpose of a filter in angular is not to modify the array, it is to select a subset of elements in the array.