# how to filter data on a table with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

So, I have this table that displays users taken from a server in angularjs. Here is the users object:

```
'users'= [
          {
            "name":"Jane Doe",
            "gender":"female",
            "role":"admin"
          },
          {
            "name":"John Doe",
            "gender":"male",
            "role":"owner"
          }
   ]
```

Here is the table that displays this data:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3>Filter by user role</h3>    
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="roleOrder">
            <option 
                ng-repeat="user in users" 
                value="{{user.role}}">{{user.role}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>role</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{role: roleOrder}">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
            <td>{{user.role}}</td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is, when the page loads, nothing gets displayed until I select a role from the dropdown to filter the `users`.

My goal is to have all the users displayed initially, and then to filter the users by their roles once their corresponding role is selected in the `option select` dropdown.

Is there a better way than the one I'm attempting? Or how do I do it right?
Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Is your users data being fetched through an async call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add function for it like here [AngularJS custom filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474091/angularjs-custom-filter-function)

In js file

```
$scope.predicate = function( roleOrder ) {
  return function( item ) {
    return !roleOrder || item.role === roleOrder;
  };
};
```

And in html

```
 <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:predicate(roleOrder)">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
        <td>{{user.role}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

user data is displaying when page loads, its working fine. Can you check the below link.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FwqivguAcyLnqxKVWEC6?p=preview

```
 $scope.users= [
          {
            "name":"Jane Doe",
            "gender":"female",
            "role":"admin"
          },
          {
            "name":"John Doe",
            "gender":"male",
            "role":"owner"
          }
   ]
```

Is this you expectation, it not please explain it briefly.
Check whether the data from server binds in $scope when the page loads